# Pandas Concat new column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, concatenation

Why do i get NaN in 'ACTION' column?
It seems strange to me that i am getting that result. I have tried using ignore_index = True and it has a freq error.

```
                        C     H     L     O     OI       V   WAP  ACTION
datetime                                                                
2017-03-14 00:52:00  8.25  8.25  8.19  8.21  302.0  1769.0  8.22     NaN
2017-03-13 23:54:00  8.09  8.10  8.09  8.10    6.0    65.0  8.10     NaN
2017-03-14 01:03:00  8.29  8.32  8.28  8.29  175.0  1084.0  8.30     NaN
2017-03-14 00:03:00  8.15  8.15  8.14  8.15   13.0    50.0  8.15     NaN
2017-03-13 23:57:00  8.13  8.13  8.12  8.12    3.0     6.0  8.12     NaN
```

I want to get -

```
                        C     H     L     O     OI       V   WAP  ACTION
datetime                                                                
2017-03-14 00:52:00  8.25  8.25  8.19  8.21  302.0  1769.0  8.22     100
2017-03-13 23:54:00  8.09  8.10  8.09  8.10    6.0    65.0  8.10     200
2017-03-14 01:03:00  8.29  8.32  8.28  8.29  175.0  1084.0  8.30     300
2017-03-14 00:03:00  8.15  8.15  8.14  8.15   13.0    50.0  8.15     400
2017-03-13 23:57:00  8.13  8.13  8.12  8.12    3.0     6.0  8.12     500

buy_stp = pd.Series([100,200,300,400,500],name= 'ACTION')
print(buy_stp)
df10 = pd.concat([df_concat_results,
                  buy_stp],
                  axis=1,
                  join_axes=[df_concat_results.index])

print(df10)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need same indexes - `Series` with `DataFrame` for alignment else get `NaN`s:

```
buy_stp.index = df.index
df['ACTION'] = buy_stp
print (df)
                        C     H     L     O     OI       V   WAP  ACTION
datetime                                                                
2017-03-14 00:52:00  8.25  8.25  8.19  8.21  302.0  1769.0  8.22     100
2017-03-13 23:54:00  8.09  8.10  8.09  8.10    6.0    65.0  8.10     200
2017-03-14 01:03:00  8.29  8.32  8.28  8.29  175.0  1084.0  8.30     300
2017-03-14 00:03:00  8.15  8.15  8.14  8.15   13.0    50.0  8.15     400
2017-03-13 23:57:00  8.13  8.13  8.12  8.12    3.0     6.0  8.12     500
```

Or:

```
buy_stp = pd.Series([100,200,300,400,500],name= 'ACTION', index=df.index)
print(buy_stp)
datetime
2017-03-14 00:52:00    100
2017-03-13 23:54:00    200
2017-03-14 01:03:00    300
2017-03-14 00:03:00    400
2017-03-13 23:57:00    500
Name: ACTION, dtype: int64

df['ACTION'] = buy_stp
print (df)
                        C     H     L     O     OI       V   WAP  ACTION
datetime                                                                
2017-03-14 00:52:00  8.25  8.25  8.19  8.21  302.0  1769.0  8.22     100
2017-03-13 23:54:00  8.09  8.10  8.09  8.10    6.0    65.0  8.10     200
2017-03-14 01:03:00  8.29  8.32  8.28  8.29  175.0  1084.0  8.30     300
2017-03-14 00:03:00  8.15  8.15  8.14  8.15   13.0    50.0  8.15     400
2017-03-13 23:57:00  8.13  8.13  8.12  8.12    3.0     6.0  8.12     500
```

Also works if convert to `numpy array` by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) or `list`, only is necessary same length `df` and `buy_stp`:

```
df['ACTION'] = buy_stp.values
print (df)
                        C     H     L     O     OI       V   WAP  ACTION
datetime                                                                
2017-03-14 00:52:00  8.25  8.25  8.19  8.21  302.0  1769.0  8.22     100
2017-03-13 23:54:00  8.09  8.10  8.09  8.10    6.0    65.0  8.10     200
2017-03-14 01:03:00  8.29  8.32  8.28  8.29  175.0  1084.0  8.30     300
2017-03-14 00:03:00  8.15  8.15  8.14  8.15   13.0    50.0  8.15     400
2017-03-13 23:57:00  8.13  8.13  8.12  8.12    3.0     6.0  8.12     500
```

---

```
df['ACTION'] = buy_stp.tolist()
print (df)
                        C     H     L     O     OI       V   WAP  ACTION
datetime                                                                
2017-03-14 00:52:00  8.25  8.25  8.19  8.21  302.0  1769.0  8.22     100
2017-03-13 23:54:00  8.09  8.10  8.09  8.10    6.0    65.0  8.10     200
2017-03-14 01:03:00  8.29  8.32  8.28  8.29  175.0  1084.0  8.30     300
2017-03-14 00:03:00  8.15  8.15  8.14  8.15   13.0    50.0  8.15     400
2017-03-13 23:57:00  8.13  8.13  8.12  8.12    3.0     6.0  8.12     500
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you just want to add a column to a data frame. If so, this is the easiest way to do it.

```
df['Action'] = buy_stp
```

Comment: That is what i was trying to do. It seems that my indexes need to be the same as Jezrael has pointed out below.